# SQL Server: Using triggers for workflow automation

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

In a media management system my task is to create a workflow automation. Currently, i have created it using SQL Server triggers and the UI using ASP.NET with JQuery.

For Ex:

When a new file enters the system the trigger works and it will update the database metadata table with some data for that file.

Millions of assets get through the system. Is it ideal to have triggers to do this process.

Is there a better way to create this automation? 
Is there a "best practice" to do this kind of works?

Comment: Perhaps a SSIS package run on a schedule by SQL Server agent? Please can you give more details on what you mean by "a new file enters the system"?

Comment: Well, now that the mysql guys got dragged over here, what shall the close vote reason be ? :p

Comment: Any code run by a trigger causes the client performing the data operation to wait. Any errors that occur in the trigger cause the original data operation to be rolled back. Consider using something like RabbitMq.

Comment: @ErikE thankyou for suggestion. Is there any sample implementation of SQL Server queries or triggers with RabbitMq.

Comment: @Bridge It is a media management system so media files are indexed in the database the process of indexing starts when we upload a file from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and data enters my central asset database on several ways (may differ from client to client).
So I also want to create an easily customizable workflow in the data layer (no other dependencies)
As the other people mention, triggers may affect the parent activity.
That is overcome by writing your action that should be performed away to a queue table.

Example Trigger. Hardware.Status = "Issue Work Order"

```
INSERT INTO Queue (Created, Task, Completed) VALUES (GETUTCDATE(),"EXEC dbo.IssueWorkOrder(123)",0);
```

The insert of a record into your queue table will reduce the problems as highlighted by other user comments.

The you build a scheduling tool (hangfire, sql tasks, or whatever), that execute tasks in the queue in the data order it wAS added.

Now, of course in practice it's not as simple as that. You will have to address the following:

1. What if the step fails2
2. Dependencies of previous steps to first have been completed
3. Multiple operators changing a record. (the deploy time between the job step being executed, and another person updating the same record.

I guess #2 and #3 is an issue with any workflow engine / pipleline. To address this a locking mechanism must be put in place.